# 'Access Denied' when copying files on AWS through the Node SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm currently writing an application in Node which has to be able to create, delete and copy files in a bucket. The create and delete functions work like a charm but the issue is with the 'copyObject' function (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property). It's returning an error saying 'Access Denied'.

I did some research and tried different Bucket policies but nothing seems to work. This is the policy I'm currently using:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1458587151478",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicList",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        }
    ]
}
```

(where bucketname is the name of my bucket)

The code I use to copy the file is:

```
  copyJson:function(creativeData, callback){

    var s3 = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'bucketname'}});

    var params = {
      CopySource: 'json_files/' + creativeData.user_id + '/'+creativeData.old_id + '.json',
      Key: 'json_files/' + creativeData.user_id + '/' + creativeData.new_id + '.json',
      ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control'
    };

    s3.copyObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) callback(err, null);
      else     callback(null, data);
    });

  }
```

The error is:

```
{
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "code": "AccessDenied",
    "region": null,
    "time": "2016-03-22T09:02:25.761Z",
    "requestId": "45EE85638A6099DD",
    "extendedRequestId": "ag6GzYUc5gyZ1AuNQXpcLEgMI/ry814fS5oG66JwU3+4EfEuwfmAY2vagXemAkAJWyMx9EgvQ/8=",
    "statusCode": 403,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 3.5066229524090886
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your IAM role only gives access to GetObject and ListObject. Copying also requires PutObject as you write to S3. I think this should work:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1458587151478",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": ["s3:GetObject","s3:PutObject"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicList",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        }
    ]
}
```